# everytime change textbox update dependable textbox excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update the user form start date and end date which depends on the contract date
when I change the contract date, the start and end dates don't change
** Date in the textbox contract date shown automatically as of the date of today, so when I changed that day start and end dates remains as were

```
Select Case Me.Plancombo
Case "6 Years"
If Contractdate.Value = "" Then startdate.Value = ""

If IsDate(Contractdate.Text) Then
  startdate.Value = DateAdd("M", 3, Contractdate)
  startdate.Value = Format(startdate, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
  
  Enddate.Text = DateAdd("M", 69, Contractdate)
  Enddate.Value = Format(Enddate, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
  On Error Resume Next
End If
Case "7 Years"
If IsDate(Contractdate.Text) Then
  startdate.Text = DateAdd("M", 3, Contractdate)
  startdate.Value = Format(startdate, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
  
  Enddate.Text = DateAdd("M", 81, Contractdate)
  Enddate.Value = Format(Enddate, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

Comment: Whar value of contract date did you enter . What is your windows short date format .

Comment: date of today, and it is auto show as today date (DD-MMM-YYYY)

Comment: I tried to recreate your issue but didn't encounter any issues while testing, have you gone through your code to see everything going as predicted? i.e. the date you changed it to is valid, the names are all correct, the case is either "6 years" or "7 years"?

Comment: How is the code invoked, is it a command button click  or change event ?

Comment: yes, but i need to show on user form start date depends on the contract date where the contract date is shown automatically as date of today, so when i start user form, textbox contains contract date (today) and doesn't affect dependable textbox unless write it manually

Comment: Can you show the complete subroutine